# Chat Title overlaps with Discussion

Tags: bug, chat

When you reduce your chat browser window, it starts to look ugly:

[image]

Comment: True, and this has been the case for years. Now that SE has a [fully functional mobile chat](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/273727), using it in a narrow window is a viable workaround.